# Visual Studio 2013 Editor Window Does Not Render

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I launch Visual Studio, the editor window does not render. Nor do the contents of the Output panel, or Find Results.

... I've tried restarting Visual Studio. I've tried opening different solutions. I've tried restarting my computer. I've tried searching for a solution; hard to think of the search terms to use, but I tried anyway and found nothing helpful.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6C4u.png]

Comment: Try changing the check box for `Tools` > `Options` > `Environment` > `General` > `Use hardware graphics acceleration`, or maybe `Enable rich client visual experience`.